# The Devel module query log doesn't appear in a custom theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

The Devel module query log appears correctly (at the bottom of the page) when I use one of the default themes, but not when I switch to my custom theme. The query log seems to appear within the inner pages in the custom theme, though not the front page or administrator pages (if those are set to use the custom theme).

I have been through page.tpl.php and html.tpl.php and I can't see any missing variables.

How does the query log get printed on the page?

Comment: Did you add the block in your custom theme? Structure => Blocks

Comment: There is no block for this. I can remove all blocks from the theme (apart from the required content one) and it still shows up in the system theme and not  in the custom theme.

Comment: You need to check 'Collect query info' in the devel settings: `admin/config/development/devel `

Also go through the permissions of the user that you are checking. Make sure you are checking with admin

Comment: Permissions are OK, settings are OK.

Comment: Do you use different templates for the pages where it shows or doesn't show? Might be something missing there?

Comment: Yep, the custom theme is a custom template, but as stated above I can't see anything missing.

Comment: How are you actually logging? `dpm($variable)`? Did you ensure to print `$messages` in your custom theme?

Comment: There already are lots of answers over on DA https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/24217/15055

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1:**

*Check in your template.php you can find the next hooks. If it doesnt exists, create it.*

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['messages'] = theme('status_messages');
}

function YOUTRHEME_status_messages($variables) {
  
  $m = drupal_get_messages();

  foreach ($m as $type => $messages) {
    if (count($messages) > 0) {
        $output .= "<div class=\"messages\">";
          $output .= " <ul>";

            foreach ($messages as $key => $message) {

              if (count($messages) > 0) {
                $output .= '<li class="message '.$type.'"><span class="text">'. $message . "</span></li>";
              }
            }

          $output .= " </ul>";
        $output .= "</div>";
    }
  }
  return $output;
}
```

**STEP 2**
*In your template check if var $message is printed. If it doesnt exists, create it.*

```
print $message;
```